# is there a way to set dynamic field names in lightning:input like below?

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I am trying to bind the fieldname from iteration into lightning:input component. Can someone help how to bind the fieldname with the attribute.
emphasized text

```
layoutType="FULL"
 mode="EDIT"

 targetRecord="{!v.newRFA}"
 targetFields="{!v.simpleNewRFA}"
 targetError="{!v.newRFAError}" />
```

Comment: <force:recordData aura:id="RFARecordCreator"
    layoutType="FULL"
     mode="EDIT"
     targetRecord="{!v.newRFA}"
     targetFields="{!v.simpleNewRFA}"
     targetError="{!v.newRFAError}" /> 
<aura:iteration items="{!Header.ModelTabQuestions__r}" var="Q">
                          <div class="{!Q.column__c}">
                                        <lightning:input type="{!Q.FieldType__c}" class="slds-m-around_x-small" name="input1"  label="{!Q.Questions__c}" value="{!v.simpleNewRFA+Q.FieldName__c}"/>
                                        </div>    </aura:iteration></div>